# ASP.NET Web Site to Web Application conversion error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, vs-web-site-project

We had a Visual Studio Website project.
We needed a .VBPROJ so I had to convert our Web Site Project to a Web Application Project.
I followed several walktrough, did everything well for the conversion :

- create new webapp project
- add references
- copy files (from website
  to webapp folder)
- include them in the project
- click "Convert to Web App".

After all that , i get three identical compilation errors, javascript related with an .ASPX page.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile ="~/GAR.master" Inherits="GARWA._Default" Codebehind="Default.aspx.vb" %>

'TableWeekID' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
//Very important variable! 
var TableWeekTag = '<%=TableWeekID%>'
var DivYearSmallTableTag = '<%=DivYearSmallTable%>' 
var TableNameTag = '<%=TableNameID%>'
```

What's the problem here ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript...

Comment: I don't think the error comes directly from the javascript lines because the same code is working 100% in the Web Site Type project. It's more because of the conversion and the <%@ Page  Language... @%> line. But here's the Javascript related <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    //Very important variable!
    var TableWeekTag = '<%=TableWeekID%>'
    var DivYearSmallTableTag = '<%=DivYearSmallTable%>'
    var TableNameTag = '<%=TableNameID%>'

Comment: How are you declaring the variable `TableWeekID` in the code behind?

Comment: It's not, it's an ASP.NET tag, var TableWeekTag = '<%=TableWeekID%>'. This exact code is working A-1 in the Web Site type of Project but no in this newly Web Application Project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way.

Use a Hiddenfield control and store the server variable value in it.
One hidden field for each server variable.
And get the value into the javascript function document.getElementById()

Use the below to POPULATE the serverside input control(s) datavalues first.

```
ASPX SERVERSIDE CODE

svrTableWeek.Value = TableWeekID
svrDivYear.Value = DivYearSmallTable
svrTableName.Value = TableNameID
```

Also, if you opt for the SERVERSIDE Inputs then you need the following HTML in your ASP page

```
USING ASP SERVER CONTROLS FOR HIDDEN VALUES

<asp:HiddenField ID="svrTableWeek" runat="server" /> 
<asp:HiddenField ID="svrDivYear" runat="server" /> 
<asp:HiddenField ID="svrTableName" runat="server" />
```

And if you prefer CLIENTSIDE inputs then use the code below instead of **ALL** of the above

```
USING HTML (clientside) CONTROLS FOR HIDDEN VALUES

<input type="hidden" id="svrTableWeek" name="svrTableWeek" value="<%=TableWeekID%>" />
<input type="hidden" id="svrDivYear" name="svrDivYear" value="<%=DivYearSmallTable%>" />
<input type="hidden" id="svrTableName" name="svrTableName" value="<%=TableNameID%>" />
```

Finally regardless of which of the two above methods you choose, 
now your ready to re-use those values in your clientside javascript

```
CLIENT SIDE SCRIPT ROUTINES

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
//Very important variable! 
var sTableWeek = document.getElementById('svrTableWeek').value;
var sDivYear = document.getElementById('svrDivYear').value;
var sTableName = document.getElementById('svrTableName').value;
```

It seems a bit long winded I know, but it should work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try global replacing all of the "~/GAR with "GAR .  I just converted a Web Site to a Web App, had similar odd errors, all because the virtual reference to the master page files was no longer correct.  My first indicator was a DIV ID that wasn't seen in a code-behind file.